# How to create custom language for OSX

Tags: macos

I am searching for a tool, app or steps to take to create a custom language pack for OSX. I am, for example, trying to replace all system dialog "Yes" to "Yup".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no centralized easy way to do this, and attempting it may break your software because it would violate code signing. Most all software in macOS is cryptographically signed to ensure the system won't run any software that's been hacked/infected/corrupted.

System Integrity Protection (SIP, a.k.a. rootless mode), in place since macOS 10.11 El Capitan, also makes it a hassle to edit most of the OS.

Ignoring that, you might try to go about it something like this:

Inside every .app and similar software "bundle" or "package" directories are a set of language resource ".lproj" directories, one for each language supported.

For example, the US English localization resources would be in /Applications/MyCoolApp.app/Contents/Resources/en-us.lproj (or maybe just "en.lproj" or "English.lproj".

They usually contain .strings files which IIRC are UTF-16 encoded name/value pairs for a lot of the strings in the UI of that app. There may also be .xib or .nib files which are UI window/widget layout files that may also contain strings, and can be edited in Xcode.

For each .app or similar bundle you want to "translate", you could duplicate one of those .lproj directories, give it a different language name, edit the .strings and .xib files, then tell the OS you want to switch to displaying in that other language.

Overall I give it a very high hassle factor and low chance of success/satisfaction.

Comment: Indeed - the effort isn't worth the outcome at this point for me, thanks.